# Best/most performant way to add function methods within a different function in Julia

Tags: performance, methods, julia, method-dispatch

In my problem, I have a function, say `optim`, that takes as one of its arguments another function, say `objfunc`, along with some other arguments:

`optim(objfunc, args...)`

I wish to call this function within another function, let's call it `run_expt`, and pass a value for `objfunc` that I have set to be a specific method of some other function `myfunc`.

So specifically, say if `myfunc` took four arguments:

`myfunc(a, b, c, d)`

and I wanted a specific method for it to pass to `optim`, which fixed the values of some of its arguments:

`mymethod(a) = myfunc(a, [1, 2, 3], (12.0, 47), false)`

and those values were determined within the function `run_expt` in a way that was not known ahead of time. What is the best way to achieve this, particularly if the method `mymethod` is to be performant when called by `optim` as it is to be called many times.

I can see two possible ways of doing this, and I would like to know if there is one that is preferred for some stylistic or performance reason, or if - more likely - there is a better way entirely.

**Approach #1** nested function:

```
function myfunc(a, b, c, d)
    ...
end

function run_expt(exptargs)
    ...
    mymethod(a) = myfunc(a, [1, 2, 3], (12.0, 47), false)
    ...
    optim(mymethod, args...)
    ---
end
```

**Approach #2** using another function which returns methods:

```
function myfunc(a, b, c, d)
    ...
end

function gen_method(methargs...)
    ...
    mymethod(a) = myfunc(a, [1, 2, 3], (12.0, 47), false)
    ...
    return mymethod
end

function run_expt(exptargs...)
    ...
    mymethod = gen_method(methargs...)
    ...
    optim(mymethod, args...)
    ---
end
```

Are there distinct advantages/disadvantages to either approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Am on phone but the typical way to deal with this is using anonymous functions. Julia has a nice compact syntax for them and a section in the docs with examples. They are as performant as native functions as of v0.5+

Comment: Agreed. You should _absolutely_ use anonymous functions here. Using your own example, you define it like this: `mymethod = a -> myfunc(a, [1, 2, 3], (12.0, 47), false)`

Comment: So using the same code from approach #1 but with this anonymous function declaration? Is there an advantage to the function being anonymous over the other approaches?

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two approaches. If there is nothing type-unstable, `gen_method` is simply inlined and the resulting codes are identical. You can make a minimum concrete (i.e., runnable) example and look at the resulting code with `@code_typed` or `@code_native`.