# Inside a function, how do I construct a new function based on original function parameters, in order to pass as an argument to another function

Tags: performance, scope, functional-programming, julia

I'm having trouble with function declarations and scope in julia. I have a main function, let's call it `mainfunc` which accepts some arguments. Within this function, I would ultimately like to call a different function, say `callfunc`, which takes a function as an argument. This function I will call `passfunc`.

One further complication I have is that there is a final function which I define outside of the logic which depends on the arguments but still depends on the arguments in a different way. I can call this `initfunc`. This must be composed with some other function, depending on the arguments, to create `passfunc`.

Based on the arguments given to `mainfunc`, I will have different definitions of `passfunc`. Given the answer I got to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941318/best-most-performant-way-to-add-function-methods-within-a-different-function-in), I initially tried to define my function logic in the following way, using anonymous functions which are apparently more efficient:

```
function mainfunc(args)

    init_func = x -> funcA(x, args)

    if args[1] == "foo"
        anon_func = x -> func1(x, args)
    elseif args[1] == "bar"
        anon_func = x -> func2(x, args)
    end

    function passfunc(x)
        return init_func(x) + anon_func(x)
    end

    # ... define other args...

    callfunc(passfunc, other_args)
end
```

Defining my function in this way leads to errors in julia - apparently `passfunc` is an undefined variable when I run this code. Does the scope not allow the anonymous functions to be defined in the if statements? How else could I write code that achieves this?

I feel like a better understanding of functional programming principles would make the solution here obvious. Thank you in advance for any tips you can offer on improving this.

Also, I am running this with julia v0.7

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example. When I place dummy functions in place of missing parts of your code everything works as expected.

Comment: If `args[1]` is in not "foo" nor "bar", `anon_func()`  will be indeed undefined! Which will fail in `passfunc()`.

Comment: Indeed, it turned out that my error was due to an unrelated mistake... I was re-using a variable name from within the if-else block that must have confused julia